# Ember not loading embedded polymorphic relationship

Tags: ember.js, polymorphic-associations

I'm using Ember's RESTAdapter and have a pretty standard polymorphic relationship:

```
// models/order.js
import DS from 'ember-date';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  transferableItem: DS.belongsTo('transferable-item', { polymorphic: true })
});

// models/transferable-item.js
import DS from 'ember-date';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  order: DS.belongsTo('order')
});

// models/ticket.js
import TransferableItem from './transferable-item';
export default TransferableItem.extend();
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "orders": [{
    "id": 111,
    "transferableItem": 999
    "transferableItemType": "Ticket"
  }],
  "tickets": [{
    "id": 999
  }]
}
```

Looking in Ember Inspector, both Orders and Tickets properly load. However, the link between the two of them is broken. I get this error:

> You looked up the 'transferableItem' relationship on a 'order' with id
>   999 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make
>   sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify
>   that the relationship is async (`DS.belongsTo({ async: true })`)

According to Ember Inspector, there are no `transferable-item`s loaded, so in a way, this error makes sense. However, since this is a polymorphic relationship, shouldn't it just try to use the associated Ticket, which is in fact loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Kept on digging, and discovered that the syntax needs to change when the record is embedded. The JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "orders": [{
    "id": 111,
    "transferableItem": {
      "id": 999
      "type": "ticket"
    }
  }],
  "tickets": [{
    "id": 999
  }]
}
```